# Total charge in an insulated dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dielectric

Is it trivial that the total charge in an insulated polarized dielectric is zero??

My T.A. mentioned it in class but I didn't quite got how the "insulated" part of the affirmation could lead to this result.

I imagine it has to do with "$\sigma_b$" and "$\rho_b$" (bound as Griffiths uses) but don't quite get it mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

If the dielectric is neutral before we apply an external field, then it must stay neutral if it is insulated, since there isn't a way for any charges to be put on or be taken off the dielectric (by definition of insulated). The polarization just moves charges around, it doesn't change the net charge. "Trivial" is, of course, a subjective word, but I would say this is trivial.